# Checking message length with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to determine the length of a message in a channel. I can't find what to put for the message length, I tried this on a channel that isn't mine, and it didn't seem to work, no error code were thrown, it just doesn't work.

---

This is my code so far:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("connected");
});

bot.on('message', (message) => {
  if(message.channel.id === '549389103071969869') {
    if(message.length !== '4') {
      message.delete()
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: [`message.content.length`?](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content)

Answer (score 1):

The `message` parameter is the entire [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object. For example, [`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author), [`message.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=id), etc.

What you are looking for is [`message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content), the actual text in the message.

Also, make sure the number you're comparing the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property to is a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), not a [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) as it is now.

```js
if (message.content.length !== 4) { // 4, not "4"
```

---

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use [`message.content.length`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content). `message.length` will return undefined as `.length` doesn't work on an object property.

---

[image]

---

What you want to use is `message.content.length` to find the length of `message.content`.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

As you can see in the first picture, it returned `undefined`. And then in the second picture, it shows the content of the message, which is what we wanted, and lastly the third one (for `eval` purposes i used `message.channel.messages.cache.get()` to get the exact message in the second picture) is the message content's length.

---

For your code, the answer will be as such:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("connected");
});

bot.on('message', (message) => {
  if(message.channel.id === '549389103071969869') {
    
    // Use `message.content.length`
    if(message.content.length !== 4) {
    // Do mind that '4' is a string, and what you want is the length (a number), so you shouldn't put quotes around it.

      // If the message length isn't 4, then delete it.
      message.delete()
    }
  }
});
```

---

For more information, visit the links below:

- [Discord.js.org - Docs - Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Message)
- [Discord.js.org - Docs - Message#Content](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content)
- [W3Schools - Guide, Docs - String length Property](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_length_string.asp)
- [TechOnTheNet - Guide - String length Property](https://www.techonthenet.com/js/string_length.php)
- [MDN web docs - Guide - String length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

These are the docs on how I used `message.channel.messages.cache.get()`.

- [Discord.js.org - Docs - MessageManager#Cache](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=cache)
- [Discord.js.org - Docs - Collection#Get](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get)